# OpenCV - extract still opaque TV channel logos

Tags: python, opencv

my goal is to extract region on a video about still opaque TV channel logos.

I've started to play with this code in Python that create a framed average output

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
c = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
_,f = c.read()

avg1 = np.float32(f)
avg2 = np.float32(f)

while(1):
    _,f = c.read()
    cv2.accumulateWeighted(f,avg1,0.1)
    cv2.accumulateWeighted(f,avg2,0.01)
    res2 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(avg2)
    cv2.imshow('img',f)
    cv2.imshow('avg2',res2)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
c.release()
```

This is how it looks after video is processing:

[image]

After the time averaging, most of the objects in the frame become blurred, except the logo and perhaps some other time-invariant objects.

My question is: how can i detect "the most" static region, in order to cut and save as images from the video?

Comment: You could calculate the variance, or standard deviation, at each pixel position over time and choose the area where that is a minimum.

Comment: Any sample code pls?